# Navigation bar sub menus with full width of navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to achieve an effect similar to the image below:

[image]

However, I am struggling to get the sub menu aligned, and get the width of the sub menu to be the same as the full navigation bar:

```css
        body {
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        .item {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }

            .item a {
                padding: 10px;
                border: 1px black solid;
                margin: 1px;
                display: block;
                width: 100px;
            }

            .item .all-subs {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background: red;
                width:100%;
            }

            .item .sub-items {
                float: left;
                margin: 0 1%;
                width: 30%;
            }
            .item:hover {
                background-color: green;
            } 
            
            .item:hover > .all-subs {
                display: block;
            }
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="nav">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <div class="all-subs">
                <div class="sub-items">
                    <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 4
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 5
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 6
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-items">
                    <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 2
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="sub-items">
                    <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-item">
                        Sub 2
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <div class="all-subs">

            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 3
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 4
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 5
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 6
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <div class="all-subs">

            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 3
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 4
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 5
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 6
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">Item 4</a>
        <div class="all-subs">

            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 3
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 4
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 5
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 6
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">Item 4</a>

        <div class="all-subs">

            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 3
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 4
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 5
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 6
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">Item 5</a>
        <div class="all-subs">

            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 3
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 4
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 5
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 6
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="sub-items">
                <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 1
                </div>
                <div class="sub-item">
                    Sub 2
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

With the sub menu's width set to 100%, it inherits the width of the parent div (as expected). Also, the alignment of the sub menu is level with the parent div. Is there any way to alter this behavior with CSS?

I am hoping that this will make my navigation bar responsive (to a certain extent - tablets and mobiles will need to be altered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position your `.nav` relatively and give it a `width`, remove `position: relative` from `.item` so that the `.all-subs` take full `width` of `.nav`.

<kbd>**[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYLYrv)**</kbd>

```css
body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 744px;
}
.item {
  float: left;
}
.item a {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin: 1px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}
.item .all-subs {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.item .sub-items {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 30%;
}
.item:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.item:hover > .all-subs {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <div class="all-subs">
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 3
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 4
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 5
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 6
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <div class="all-subs">

        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 3
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 4
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 5
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 6
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <div class="all-subs">

        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 3
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 4
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 5
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 6
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <div class="all-subs">

        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 3
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 4
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 5
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 6
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">Item 4</a>

      <div class="all-subs">

        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 3
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 4
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 5
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 6
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
      <div class="all-subs">

        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 1</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 3
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 4
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 5
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 6
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 2</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="sub-items">
          <h2>Sub Item List 3</h2>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 1
          </div>
          <div class="sub-item">
            Sub 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```